# Add class if input is empty and remove it if not

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, addclass, removeclass

I would like to add a class if input is empty and remove it if it isn't. I initially had `addClass();` so I tried using:

```
.removeClass().addClass();
```

But it doesn't seem to update the class on the click of the button.

HTML:

```
<input id="firstName" type="text" />
<input id="lastName" type="text" />
<a href="#" id="button">SEND</a>
```

jQuery:

```
var firstName = $("#firstName");
var lastName = $("#lastName");

$('#button').click(function () {
    if(firstName.val() == "" || lastName.val() == ""){
        firstName.removeClass("errorInput").addClass("errorInput");
        lastName.removeClass("errorInput").addClass("errorInput");
    }

if ($(":input").hasClass("errorInput")) {
        alert("false");
    } else {
        alert("true");
    }
});
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0tfenwto/1/)**

Comment: You are removing a class and then adding it right back in.

Comment: Yuck, it bothers me when the titles don't reflect the content.  Title doesn't say anything about "on click"  :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to [toggle the class](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). There's a method for that!

Quoting from the linked doc:

> The second version of .toggleClass() uses the second parameter for
>   determining whether the class should be added or removed. If this
>   parameter's value is true, then the class is added; if false, the
>   class is removed. In essence, the statement:
>
> ```
> $( "#foo" ).toggleClass( className, addOrRemove );
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> if ( addOrRemove ) {
>   $( "#foo" ).addClass( className );
> } else {
>   $( "#foo" ).removeClass( className );
> }
> ```

Something along the lines of `firstName.toggleClass("errorInput", firstName.val() === "")` should work for your case.

Comment: `firstName.toggleClass("errorInput", firstName.val() === "")`

Comment: toggle just toggles the class on button click regardless of the input being empty or nto

Comment: Toggle can accept a conditional argument indicating whether to toggle the class on or off.

Comment: @Hamms Put that in the answer

Comment: @Hamms woah... didn't know toggle class accepted another parameter. Thank you!!

Comment: Toggling the class is the wrong thing to do for validation purposes. The class should be added/removed based on validation rules.

Comment: That's exactly what it's doing.

Answer (score 4):

You can set some class to the input fields, or select em like this:

```
var firstName = $("#firstName");
var lastName = $("#lastName");

$('#button').click(function () {

  $('input').each(function(){

    if($this.val().trim()){
      $(this).addClass("errorInput");
    }
    else{
      $(this).removeClass("errorInput");
    }

  });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't take into consideration the case where one input is empty and the other isn't.

https://jsfiddle.net/0tfenwto/2/

```
if(firstName.val() == "")
    firstName.addClass("errorInput");
else
    firstName.removeClass("errorInput")

if(lastName.val() == "")
    lastName.addClass("errorInput");
else
    lastName.removeClass("errorInput")
```

EDIT: Generic input length checker.
https://jsfiddle.net/0tfenwto/3/

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $('input').each(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        $(this).toggleClass("errorInput",val.length==0)
    })
});
```

Comment: I would rather avoid that many if blocks. I have many input fields and that is why my if statement has multiple checks on one line

Comment: Avoiding code duplication is good, however misrepresenting error states is not good. Check my edit for a generic solution.

Comment: @user4756836 - So you'll display your First Name field as being in an error state *even though it isn't* just to avoid an extra if/else? Fortunately there is a shorter way to code it, without the if/else, but even if there wasn't you really should write as much code as needed to avoid confusing the user.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add an else to your if.

```
 if(){
    // add the class
 } else {
    // remove the class
 }
```

Here's an updated fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/za7pkb74/1/