# Chrome Auto-fill is executing after my JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

In Chrome, I have created form input elements that has a label, when focused, float above the input field. This works and executes perfectly.

When I use the chrome autofill for the username and password, the browser populates the input field with the yellow prefilled text. The issue I am having is the label JS does not execute and float to the upper right when the yellow prefilled text is visible. It does auto-correct the issue if you click anywhere on the page. Any thoughts or solutions? I do need the autocomplete feature to be set.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Chrome autofills an input, it won't trigger the `:focus` state that your CSS currently relies on.  Unfortunately, no such pseudo-selector exists in CSS for detecting whether an input is filled or not ([learn more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952526/detect-if-an-input-has-text-in-it-using-css-on-a-page-i-am-visiting-and-do-no)).

Your best option is using jQuery to detect whether each of your inputs has a value and add a class if true. See the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664356/add-class-if-input-is-empty-and-remove-it-if-not). Then revise your animation effect so that it applies to `input.has-data-class`, for example.